# Configuring Swashbuckle to use Inline Schema

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

With SwashBuckle we have a project that is creating inline schema's for Array/lists:

Right it returns something like this:

```
"200": {
    "description": "Success",
    "schema": {
        "uniqueItems": false,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/SwaggerGenerationSample.Models.Response.Employee"
        }
    }
}
```

We would like to have something like this:

```
"200": {
    "description": "Success",
    "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/EmployeeArray"
    }
}
...
"definitions": {
    "EmployeeArray": {
        "uniqueItems": false,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/SwaggerGenerationSample.Models.Response.Employee"
        }
    }
}
```

What should we configure in SwashBuckle to get the result above? I created an example project to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/mvdiemen/SwaggerArrayGenerationExample

Comment: Is there a difference in the UI of one version vs the other? I would not really spend any time on this, it is all autogenerated, and to be honest the first version looks better

Comment: There is no difference in the UI between the first and second version looking at the Swagger UI. But importing it in Azure API management (that we use) is causing a wrong OpenAPI document to be generated (see above)

Answer (score 1):

Take the general guideline of [Override Schema for Specific Types](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/v4.0.0#extend-generator-with-operation-schema--document-filters) from Swashbuckle, here the [ISchemaFilter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/v4.0.0#schema-filters).

What you want is to provide your own explicit schema. With your *example project*, for any array we can use:

```cs
/**
 * code dependencies:
 * netcoreapp2.1
 * Microsoft.AspNetCore.App;2.1.*
 * Swashbuckle.AspNetCore;4.0.1
 */
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

namespace SwaggerGenerationSample
{
    public class ArraySchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            // has to be changed to enumerable later on...
            if (context.SystemType.IsArray && context.SystemType.HasElementType)
            {
                // could be generalized to any T[], for now ...
                var elemType = context.SystemType.GetElementType();
                if (elemType != typeof(SwaggerGenerationSample.Models.Response.Employee)) return;

                var name = elemType.Name + "Array";
                // add if not done already
                if (!context.SchemaRegistry.Definitions.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    context.SchemaRegistry.Definitions.Add(
                        name,
                        new Schema
                        {
                            UniqueItems = schema.UniqueItems,
                            Type = schema.Type,
                            Items = schema.Items,
                        });
                }

                // and clear the schema for the endpoint...
                schema.UniqueItems = null;
                schema.Type = null;
                schema.Items = null;
                schema.Ref = "#/definitions/" + name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We need to add the filter in your startup.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
    {
        /* your config omitted for brevity */
        config.SchemaFilter<ArraySchemaFilter>();
    }
}
```

For this to work we need to "adjust" the endpoint from `IEnumerable<T>` to `T[]`.

```cs
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(Models.Response.Employee[]))]
    /* other attributes omitted for brevity */
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployees(string companyId)
    {
        return Ok(GetEmployees());
    }
}
```

Run the app and the `swagger.json` should contain the schema as requested.
**The homework for you** would be to replace the array restriction with a `IEnumerable<>` but the code above should be enough as a proof of concept.

#### friendly reminder

With an upgrade to *.Net Core 3* (or newer) the code has to be updated - very likely. And with *Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
 5* upcoming breaking have already been announced [^1].

[^1]: See release notes here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/releases/tag/v5.0.0-rc4

Answer (score 1):

Following the same approach of ckerth answer of using [ISchemaFilter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/v5.6.2#schema-filters), I was able to get the same results using *Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5*. See the code below:

```cs
public class ArraySchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type.IsArray && context.Type.HasElementType)
        {
            var elemType = context.Type.GetElementType();

            var name = elemType.Name + "Array";
            if (!context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Add(
                    name,
                    new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        UniqueItems = schema.UniqueItems,
                        Type = schema.Type,
                        Items = schema.Items
                    });
            }

            schema.UniqueItems = null;
            schema.Type = null;
            schema.Items = null;
            schema.Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Id = name,
                Type = ReferenceType.Schema
            };
        }
    }
}
```

To add the filter in startup, the code is the same:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
    {
        /* your config omitted for brevity */
        config.SchemaFilter<ArraySchemaFilter>();
    }
}
```

And to register the response type I've used a different approach:

```cs
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Employee[]), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployees(string companyId)
    {
        return Ok(GetEmployees());
    }
}
```

Now the `swagger.json` will have the requested result.