# Is there a way to expand references in Swashbuckle to provide inline schemas?

Tags: .net-core, swashbuckle

Is there a mechanism in Swashbuckle that can prevent definitions from being created with referencing to them in parameters/responses/etc.?

By default, you might get a path that looks like this:

```json
"/profile": {
  "get": {
    "summary": "Get my profile details.",
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
    ],
    "parameters": [],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ProfileModel"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what I'd like is for it to expand the schema inline like this:

```json
"/profile": {
  "get": {
    "summary": "Get my profile details.",
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
    ],
    "parameters": [],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "schema": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "id"
            },
            "firstName": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "firstName"
            },
            "surname": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "surname"
            },
            "emailAddress": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "emailAddress"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I reviewed [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58284999/configuring-swashbuckle-to-use-inline-schema) and I don't think it's what I'm looking for (or maybe misinterpreted).

Taken a look through the Swashbuckle README to understand its capabilities but coming up short. Any help here would be most appreciated.

For additional context, looking at [the Swashbuckle PDF documentation](https://swashbuckleaspnetcore.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) in section 1.7, I essentially want to bypass or revert the action they describe as

> automatically generating a corresponding schema for user-defined reference types and reference the definition via the $ref keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into the codebase a little, it looks like it's not possible at the moment.

However, you can create a custom `ISchemaGenerator` from [the one in source](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/95cb4d370e08e54eb04cf14e7e6388ca974a686e/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SchemaGenerator/SchemaGenerator.cs) and alter the `GenerateConcreteSchema` method under the `DataType.Object` case to not return as reference and this solves the issue.